# NSOutlineView getting an assertion error when expanding items

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

Looks like my data model has some problem, so that i get this error from time to time
when expanding items. Does anyone has an idea what this assert means?

2010-10-20 03:04:47.547 test_tree[60332:613] *** Assertion failure in -NSOutlineView _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:, /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-949.54/TableView.subproj/NSOutlineView.m:1003
2010-10-20 03:04:47.548 test_tree[60332:613] Invalid parameter not satisfying: itemEntry->children == NULL

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: make sure that your model does not let an object be a child of itself.  The Outline view definitely doesn't like the same object showing up like that.